# Debugging tool to see an app get lauched by another app

Tags: debug

I have a app that I have the source for but cannot debug.  (It takes a version of Delphi that I don't have on my computer.)

That app launches another app (that I can debug).  I need some way to see the parameters used to launch the second app.  (The params are causing it to crash before I can attach a debugger.)

Is there a way that I can get some insight into the actions of the first app, or that will otherwise let me see how the second app was launched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sysinternals Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) will let you see the command line that launched any process on your system.

Comment: I use that tool all the time, but did not think of it for this!  Thanks.